# How can I add validate dimension in pixels with jquery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My jquery validate like this :

```
store: {
    rules: {
        banner: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        banner: 'The banner must be filled',
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: errorPlacement,
    highlight: highlight,
    unhighlight: unhighlight
},
```

If user not upload banner with dimension 1170 x 300 pixels there exist message like this :

> Please upload an image with 1170 x 300 pixels dimension

How can I do it?

Comment: By using `jQuery.validator.addMethod` and do pixels checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create your custom validation method

```
$.validator.addMethod('dimention', function(value, element, param) {
    if(element.files.length == 0){
        return true; <--- check here if file not added than return true for not check file dimention
    }
    var width = $(element).data('imageWidth');
    var height = $(element).data('imageHeight');
    if(width == param[0] && height == param[1]){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
},'Please upload an image with 1170 x 300 pixels dimension');
```

And you need to set parameter **imageWidth** and **imageHeight** at image change like this

> // files is id of your input

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="name" />

$('#files').change(function() {
    $('#files').removeData('imageWidth');
    $('#files').removeData('imageHeight');
    var file = this.files[0];
    var tmpImg = new Image();
    tmpImg.src=window.URL.createObjectURL( file ); 
    tmpImg.onload = function() {
        width = tmpImg.naturalWidth,
        height = tmpImg.naturalHeight;
        $('#files').data('imageWidth', width);
        $('#files').data('imageHeight', height);
    }
});
```

and call like this

```
rules: {
    banner: {
        dimention:[1170,300]
    }
}
```

Working fiddle link [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xC6nb/6/)

Comment: There exist error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. Exception occured when checking element, check the 'dimention' method`

Comment: I have change my answer you can do like that it's working perfectly with your requirements

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks

Comment: I want to ask. How to make the banner not required?

Comment: I have update my answer remove require and check in dimention method if file added than check for dimention

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not working in jquery/2.1.1 version. can you help me out.